# Permission Denied Autoware Docker

Tags: ros-melodic, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

O Learned Denizens,

This is the same question as [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/344052/got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-docker-daemon/) but the answer there - to do with groups - isn't working for me.

```
Launching autoware/autoware:1.13.0-melodic
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
```

I am in a group called docker that I created doing

```
sudo group add docker
```

...and added myself using

```
sudo usermod -aG docker damian
```

...which apparently succeeded:

```
damian@UbuntiBookPro:~$ groups
damian adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker
```

What's next on the list to try?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356687/permission-denied-autoware-docker/) by [DamianHarty](https://answers.ros.org/users/56494/damianharty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-07-08**:
After you added yourself to the `docker` group, did you either restart or log out and back in? Changes to groups don't apply until you do one of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Logging out and in again didn't do it, but restarting did. Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [DamianHarty](https://answers.ros.org/users/56494/damianharty/) with karma: 26 on 2020-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1